# Java string manipulation for validity

Tags: java, string, loops, validation, substring

Say for instance I have this string:

**"His name is Justin Hoffman"**

and need to check if it is a valid name:

In order for this to return true I need to make sure I have "His name" before "is" and I need "Justin Hoffman" after the "is" how can I check to see if I have the correct substring before "is" and the correct one after "is"

Comment: Show the line of code you tried @Roosevelt James

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried, so far? @Roosevelt James

Answer (score 1):

```
String sentence = "His name is Justin Hoffman";
String[] splitSentence = sentence.split(" is ");
String first = splitSentence[0]; // His name
String second = splitSentence[1]; // Justin Hoffman
boolean isTrue = (first.equals("His name") && second.equals("Justin Hoffman"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "His name is Justin Hoffman";

String requiredFirstName = "His name";
String requiredLastName = "Justin Hoffman";
String delimiter = " is ";

// Example 1
if (input.equals(requiredFirstName + delimiter + requiredLastName))
{
    System.out.println("The input is OK");
}

// Example 2
int posi = input.indexOf(delimiter);
if (posi > 0) // found
{
    String leftPart = input.substring(0, posi);
    String rightpart = input.substring(posi + delimiter.length());
    if (requiredFirstName.equals(leftPart) && requiredLastName.equals(rightpart))
    {
        System.out.println("The input is OK");
    }
}

// Example 3
String[] parts = input.split(delimiter);
if (requiredFirstName.equals(parts[0]) && requiredLastName.equals(parts[1]))
{
    System.out.println("The input is OK");
}
```

The second example is possibly the fastest one because it does not produce temporary strings. The third example is the slowest one. Be careful with special character in the delimiter because the `split()` function interprets the argument as a regular expression.

Comment: Say for instance rather than the first half having to be "His Name" the first half of the string before "is" can be literally anything at all, even a single character if I wanted. How would I check to make sure it is at least one character before "is"?

Comment: Take Example 2 and leave out the check of  ```requiredFirstName.equals(leftPart)```.  The expression ```posi > 0``` does already the check that you want, it means "if the delimiter has been found **after** the beginning of the string (not **at** the beginning).

Comment: Another short example: ```if (input.endsWith(delimiter+lastname))```. But this is again not the fastest solution because of the string concatenation.